# D Inline Assembler: error with function call

Tags: assembly, call, d, inline-assembly

I got a very special problem.
For a VM I need to copy code from the instruction functions to a ubyte array and then execute this array (the technic is similiar to the inline macro vm in gcc), basically it works like this:

```
__gshared void * sp = null, sb = null; //stack pointer and stack base

__gshared void add() //the function is just there to access the instruction code
{
    asm{db "INSTRUCTIONCODESTART";} //this is a key to know where the instruction code starts

    //instruction code here (sample instruction add, pops 2 values from the stack and pushes its result)
    sp += 4;
    *cast(uint*)sp += *cast(uint*)(sp - 4);

    asm{db "INSTRUCTIONCODEEND";} //this is a key to know where instruction code ends
}
```

In the Init method, every instruction code gets its own buffer, and in the buffer is every byte between the INSTRUCTIONCODESTART and the INSTRUCTIONCODEEND key. I make this array executeable through the windows VirtualProtect call.

So Far, everything works as expected, but when I try to do a function call as an instruction, I will get an error.

```
__gshared void testcall(){}

__gshared void call()
{
    asm{db "INSTRUCTIONCODESTART";} //this is a key to know where the instruction code starts

    //instruction code here (just calls a D function)
    testcall(); //this somehow throws an error

    asm{db "INSTRUCTIONCODEEND";} //this is a key to know where instruction code ends
}
```

Btw I tested the instructions with the following code

```
void instructiontest()
{
    uint dummy;
    ubyte[] buf = getFunctionCode(&add) ~ 0xC3; //gets code of instruction, appends 0xC3 at it ("ret" instruction, for test purposes only to see if it returns to the D code without errors)
    VirtualProtect(cast(void*)buf, buf.length, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dummy); //makes it executeable
    dummy = cast(uint)&buf[0];
    asm
    {
        call dummy[EBP];
    }
    print("instruction worked without errors!");
}
```

So far, every simple instruction (add, mul, sub, push0, push1, ...) works, but if I try to get the code of an instruction with a function call, it throws an error

I would be happy and very thankful about any help. (btw I need function calls in the instruction in order to let the script language communicate with D)

Comment: FYI: `__gshared` has no effect on functions, only variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really disassemble the code in order to get a clear view of what it's doing and why your code is breaking. The disassembly for your `call` function is:

```
0000000000414db8 <_D4test4callFZv>:
  414db8:   55                      push   rbp
  414db9:   48 8b ec                mov    rbp,rsp
  414dbc:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  414dc0:   53                      push   rbx
  414dc1:   41 54                   push   r12
  414dc3:   41 55                   push   r13
  414dc5:   41 56                   push   r14
  414dc7:   41 57                   push   r15
  414dc9:   49                      rex.WB
  414dca:   4e 53                   rex.WRX push rbx
  414dcc:   54                      push   rsp
  414dcd:   52                      push   rdx
  414dce:   55                      push   rbp
  414dcf:   43 54                   rex.XB push r12
  414dd1:   49                      rex.WB
  414dd2:   4f                      rex.WRXB
  414dd3:   4e                      rex.WRX
  414dd4:   43                      rex.XB
  414dd5:   4f                      rex.WRXB
  414dd6:   44                      rex.R
  414dd7:   45 53                   rex.RB push r11
  414dd9:   54                      push   rsp
  414dda:   41 52                   push   r10
  414ddc:   54                      push   rsp
  414ddd:   e8 ce ff ff ff          call   414db0 <_D4test8testcallFZv>
  414de2:   49                      rex.WB
  414de3:   4e 53                   rex.WRX push rbx
  414de5:   54                      push   rsp
  414de6:   52                      push   rdx
  414de7:   55                      push   rbp
  414de8:   43 54                   rex.XB push r12
  414dea:   49                      rex.WB
  414deb:   4f                      rex.WRXB
  414dec:   4e                      rex.WRX
  414ded:   43                      rex.XB
  414dee:   4f                      rex.WRXB
  414def:   44                      rex.R
  414df0:   45                      rex.RB
  414df1:   45                      rex.RB
  414df2:   4e                      rex.WRX
  414df3:   44                      rex.R
  414df4:   41 5f                   pop    r15
  414df6:   41 5e                   pop    r14
  414df8:   41 5d                   pop    r13
  414dfa:   41 5c                   pop    r12
  414dfc:   5b                      pop    rbx
  414dfd:   c9                      leave  
  414dfe:   c3                      ret    
  414dff:   90                      nop
```

`414dc9` is where the start marker begins, `414ddc` is where it ends (inclusive). `414de2` is where your end marker begins, `414df3` is where it ends (inclusive). So, ripping that out, we have:

```
0000000000414db8 <_D4test4callFZv>:
  414db8:   55                      push   rbp
  414db9:   48 8b ec                mov    rbp,rsp
  414dbc:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  414dc0:   53                      push   rbx
  414dc1:   41 54                   push   r12
  414dc3:   41 55                   push   r13
  414dc5:   41 56                   push   r14
  414dc7:   41 57                   push   r15
  ; code start marker here
  414ddd:   e8 ce ff ff ff          call   414db0 <_D4test8testcallFZv>
  ; code end marker here
  414df4:   41 5f                   pop    r15
  414df6:   41 5e                   pop    r14
  414df8:   41 5d                   pop    r13
  414dfa:   41 5c                   pop    r12
  414dfc:   5b                      pop    rbx
  414dfd:   c9                      leave  
  414dfe:   c3                      ret    
  414dff:   90                      nop
```

You're clearly not copying some prologue and epilogue code here. But that, in and of itself, should not be terribly problematic.

I tried this program:

```
void main()
{
    foo();
}

void foo()
{
    auto addr = &bar;

    asm { call addr; }
}

void bar()
{
    asm { naked; call baz; ret; }
}

void baz()
{
}
```

It works for me. Frankly, I can't tell where your problem is. Most of the code you pasted can't just be copied into a source file and be compiled, so it's quite hard to tell what's going wrong. I hope some of the information here can help you. You're most likely going to have to attach a debugger and find out what's wrong; don't expect to mess with low-level stuff like this without getting your hands dirty. ;)

BTW, I tested on 64-bit x86 in Linux.

Either way, what you're doing is highly unportable, undefined, etc. Be warned. It may work out, but you're working with zero guarantees.

Comment: actually, your dissassembling helped me a lot, if I copy "call testcall" to another memory location, the relative jump will not work correctly anymore, so my solution was not to copy the code to a new location, but to make a class Wrapper around the instruction code (saving the address after my key), so I just jump to the address after my instruction key and it works now

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what all the mistakes are without seeing the full disassembly of all the relevant code, but...

1. x86 code generally isn't position-independent, which means copying it to a different place and executing it there may and most often will fail.
2. You're most likely copying code that trashes registers (including `ebp` and `esp`) and the stack contents.

Comment: well I made sure I dont use any local variables (every variable is declared with __gshared, which means it has a static location somewhere, and so the ebp register doesnt get corrupted), and a function call to an empty function should dissassemble to something like "call testcall", or am I wrong?

Comment: I can't tell because I don't see all the relevant code disassemblied.