# D Templates Request

Tags: templates, inline, d

I just read the whole documentation of Templates in the D programming language but cant seem to find a way for my very simple task, for functions I need 3 assembler instructions to be inserted at the beginning of each function, I would like to automate this through a macro so I dont have to manually write it each time.

```
__gshared void jump()
{
    asm{db START_KEY;}

    //bla bla bla

    asm{mov EBX, ip;add ip,4;jmp dword ptr [EBX];db END_KEY;}
}
```

something like this should get replaced with

```
__gshared void jump()
{
    mixin starttemplate();

    //bla bla bla

    mixin endtemplate();
}
```

In C I would have done something like this

```
#define STARTASM() asm{.......}
```

but if I try something like this

```
template endtemplate()
{
    asm{mov EBX, ip;add ip,4;jmp dword ptr [EBX];db END_KEY;}
}
```

it will throw an error saying that I have to declare a variable at a template (which I dont want to, since performance is absolutely needed here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about saving the asm command as a string, and using a mixin?

```
immutable string ASM_START=q{
    asm{db START_KEY;}
}
immutable string ASM_END=q{
    asm{mov EBX, ip;add ip,4;jmp dword ptr [EBX];db END_KEY;}
}

__gshared void jump()
{
    mixin(ASM_START);
    //bla bla bla
    mixin(ASM_END);
}
```

Another option is to use the mixing to create the entire function, and pass it's signature and content(=body) as arguments:

```
string functionWithAsm(string signature,string content)(){
    return Format!(q{
        %s
        {
            asm{db START_KEY;}
            %s
            asm{mov EBX, ip;add ip,4;jmp dword ptr [EBX];db END_KEY;}
        }
        },signature,content);
}

mixin(functionWithAsm!("__gshared void jump()",q{
            /*some actual code*/
            })());
```

Answer (score 1):

Template mixins can only contain declarations ([as specified here](http://dlang.org/template-mixin.html)). If you want to insert arbitrary code you need string mixins:

```
enum startTemplate = "asm{...}";
enum endTemplate = "asm{...}";

__gshared void jump()
{
    mixin(startTemplate);
    ...etc...
    mixin(endTemplate);
}
```

You can use this mechanism to insert customized assembly which can be generated with simple D functions ([executed at compile time by the compiler!](http://dlang.org/function.html#interpretation)):

```
string customAsm(string param1, bool param2)() @property
{
    string ret = "asm{";

    // append to ret, building up some code

    return ret ~ "}";
}

void myfunc()
{
    mixin(customAsm!("foo", false));
}
```

Comment: A RAII class that does this could also remove the `begin/end` part and make it less error prone.

Comment: @pmr It would have to be a struct though (not a class), since for RAII to work, it needs to be on the stack.

Comment: @pmr What's RAII have to do it? I don't see any resource allocated here - all I see is assembly code to fit D functions to some calling convention.

Comment: @IdanArye RAII doesn't necessarily have much to do with resource allocation, much as that's what the R stands for. Any time where you have two operations that always must be paired, you can use RAII for it. You declare a struct which does the first operation when it's constructed and the second operation when it's destroyed. A classic example of this would be an autolock on a mutex. When it's constructed, it locks the mutex, and when it's destroyed (be it by exception or normal exiting of scope), the mutex is unlocked. Here, there's a start and end operation which must be paired, hence RAII.

Comment: @Jonathan If it was something that can be solved with function calls, I don't think the asker would be trying to force templates and mixins into it. To me, it looks like he's trying to fit D functions to a certain calling conventions, and that's why he needs the use assembler. A struct construction and destruction can't change the caller function's calling convention...

Comment: @IdanArye Then RAII may not be appropriate here. I have no idea what the assembly code is trying to do, so I don't know how constructing and destroying a struct would affect it. In general though, when you have paired operations like this, RAII is a good solution.

Comment: @Jonathan Agreed(though in D you can also use a `scope` guard statement), but when someone insists on using assembler, that usually means that the compiler generated code does not suit their needs.

Comment: @Jonathan OK, Mystery solved. I looked at [his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491433/d-inline-assembler-error-with-function-call), and it seems he needs that assembler to mark where the function starts and where it ends. That means RAII won't be very effective - because there is no way to force the compiler to inline the constructor and destructor.